# not all urls promissed

Tags: javascript, promise

A have a case I do not understand.
I have looked in the net trying to figure out why it does not work but I did not find a thing

I have an array of urls

```
var links = [url1,url2,url-n] // there might be up to 100 urls

function loadRates(url){

    return rp(url) // rp = require('request-promise')
        .then(rates => JSON.parse(rates))
        .then(rates => {
            return {'rates':rates,'url':url}; 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
}

let promiseRates = Promise.all(links.map( url => loadRates(url) ));

promiseRates.then(
    result => {
        if(result){
            for(var el in result){
                var rateObj = fixRateObj(result[el]['rates']);
                if(rateObj){
                    data.push(rateObj);
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    }).finally(function (){
        res.send(data);
        res.end();
    });
```

The code works but somewhy only first 15 urls from the links array are in work
Why?

Comment: `only first 15 urls from the links array are in work` so, the first 15 work, pass through to `promiseRates
                .then(
                    result`? what is the length of `result` array? what is the content of `result` array past the first 15 entries? is it possible `rateObj` is falsey for a lot of the urls?

Comment: Work in what sense? Do you get an error in your log, or it just waits to handle that data first before it continues, or some request time out?

Comment: by the way `if(result){` is redundant, as an array (which is what Promise.all will give you), is ALWAYS truthy

Comment: Perhaps the URLs you are hitting are rate limited and their trying to tell you something by limiting the number of successful hits...

Comment: the result comes back as null

Comment: if I links = links.chunk(15); and send I get results for every part

Comment: what is `links.chunk(15)`

Comment: debugging 101 - check your browser developer tools - check the requests/responses in the network tab to see what the requests are returning

Comment: FYI, if any of the promises gets rejected, the Promise.all `.then` will be ignored and `.catch` will be executed!
I would say `loadRates` has alway to resolve but with empty data in case of error so you can run your `then`

Comment: Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'chunk', {
  value: function(chunkSize) {
    var R = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += chunkSize)
      R.push(this.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    return R;
  }
});

Comment: @Tareq - `I would say loadRates has alway to resolve` you're stating that it does always resolve, right, and never rejects

Comment: so, using you `chunk` method, you get an array of arrays ... and then how do you call your code, since it's expecting a flat array

Comment: nevermind that ... have you checked the responses in the browser developer tools? have you considered a comment by HereticMonkey? scary name, but that would seem to be sage advice

Comment: Please don't ever iterate an array with `for(var el in result)`.  That iterates properties of an object and is not meant for an array.  It might work sometimes, but also may not work in some other circumstances.  Use `for (let item of result)`.